# Adding to String array and reference

Tags: c++, arrays

I have dynamic string's array:

```
string *acc = new string[2];
string some_string;
```

I would like to add two strings to this array, but there is problem with reference ( i think).

I have following example (very ugly, but it shows the problem):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {

     if ( i == 0 )
        some_string = "ab";
     else 
        some_string = "cd";
     acc[i] = some_string;
     some_string = "";
}
return acc
```

Of course this code is without any sense, but my code is more complicated and it would hide the problem.
The point is that code is returning `cd` instead of `abcd`. In my opinion `some_string = "";` make mess here. Am I right? 
Is it possible to do it keeping logic of code?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There is probably a better way to do it than this.

Comment: Please avoid pointers

Comment: You are not comparing i and 0 your are assigning it. Use `i == 0` instead

Comment: typo questions are off-topic. also use `std::vector`.

Comment: It would be much safer to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of an array of strings.  Or, better yet: `using StringVector = std::vector<std::string>;`

Comment: That code should not compile.

Comment: Well now I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/708cab7d15646ade) your problem.

Comment: Because original question had bug, which is now removed.

@Ojmeny If you ask a question and provide buggy code, do not remove these bugs. Now your question is meaningless, since your code after edit is the answer (although it is still very error-prone).

Comment: @Ojmeny  - I think the real problem is the "expected result", i.e. how is the returned acc used. Explain what you want to achieve. Show the code calling the function and what you do afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

No, you simply made a bug:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {

     if ( i == 0 ) // == instead of = !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        some_string = "ab";
     else 
        some_string = "cd";
     acc[i] = some_string;
     some_string = "";
}
return acc;
```

Think over using a std::vector or std::list instead of pointer too. With a vector, your code looks like:

```
std::vector<std::string> vs;
```

...and later...

```
vs.push_back("ab");
vs.push_back("cd");
```

Comment: Sorry, for not checking my code :( It should be `i == 0`

Comment: ...or just `std::vector<std::string> vs {"ab", "cd"};`

Comment: @JerryCoffin on initilizing, yes. I wanted to show a solution near to his existing code. I update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you should write code this way. And you don't need temporary `some_string` - assigning strings is well-defined and do exactly what it should. In thi case, use `vector` - it is **much** safer approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> ac;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            ac.push_back("ab");
        else
            ac.push_back("cd");
    }

    cout<<ac[0]<<ac[1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Working sample: [here](http://ideone.com/2X6Jkv).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you expect "abcd" as result.
You assign some_string the value "cd" instead of adding to "ab".

Maybe this is what you are trying:

```
string* func()
{
    string *acc = new string[2];
    string some_string;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) 
    {

        if ( i == 0 )
            some_string = "ab";                 // "ab"
         else
            some_string = some_string + "cd";   // "ab" + "cd" -> "abcd"

         acc[i] = some_string;
         //some_string = "";
    }
    return acc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string* y = func();

    cout << y[0] <<  endl;  // First element "ab"
    cout << y[1] <<  endl;  // Second element "abcd"

    // Other stuff
    // ....

    // Remember to delete y

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
ab
abcd
```

But as others had said.... Use vector instead.

You could also use std::array like this:

```
array<string, 2> func2()
{
    array<string, 2> res;
    string some_string;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ )
    {

        if ( i == 0 )
            some_string = "ab";
         else
            some_string = some_string + "cd";

         res[i] = some_string;
    }

    // Or just this instead of a for loop
    // res[0] = "ab";
    // res[1] = "abcd";

    return res;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    array<string, 2> z = func2();

    cout << z[0] <<  endl;
    cout << z[1] <<  endl;

    return(0);
}
```